# Why json-patch changing the Date format

Tags: java, date-format, json-patch

I am using json patch 1.13 version to apply patch on my json payload .

This is the POM Entry using for json patch

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-patch</artifactId>
  <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>
```

The existing payload have value like

```
{
 "expirationDate": "2022-05-15T01:59:59"
}
```

I am applying the patch with below patch operation, . This is to update the value with new date .

```
[
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/expirationDate",
    "value": "2023-05-15T02:59:59"
}
]
```

But after applying the patch the new object have differently formatted Date value like

```
Java code
JsonNode patched = patch.apply(objectMapper.convertValue(targetCustomer, JsonNode.class));
return objectMapper.treeToValue(patched, Customer.class);

Output
expirationDate=Mon May 15 01:59:59 EDT 2023

Expected Output
expirationDate: "2023-05-15T01:59:59"

Any reason its changing the format or how i can fix this.
```

Comment: What is `patch`? What JSON libraries are you using? Please provide a minimal reproducible example as explained in the help center page: http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Where exactly is the "output" coming from? Is it possible that you're actually seeing the result of calling `toString()` on a `java.util.Date`? (In which case it's got nothing to do with the patch.)

Comment: The formatted date i am seeing on patched object.  I can see the formatted date when i am calling toString on that Object.

Comment: In another way to explain , say i am applying same date on patch like [
{
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/expirationDate",
    "value": "2022-05-15T02:59:59"
}
] So the existing and new object have same value . But if i call 
   existingObject.equals(newpatchedObjt)   should say its same . But in this case because of the Date format difference its saying the objects are not equal.